# Add HTML element after text

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to add an HTML element using JavaScript. But the problem is that the new element might be in between some text. In all other cases I'm using the insertBefore() method.

I am using the following function to get the cursor position. 
My initial approach was to split the target innerHTML and add the necessary tags but the cursor position provided does not take into account the character conversions such as space to  `&nbsp;`. So if there are multiple continous spaces, the cursor position will not give the coreect position int he innerHTML.

```
function getCursorPos()
{
var cursorPos=-1;
if (window.getSelection)
{
    var selObj = window.getSelection();
    var selRange = selObj.getRangeAt(0);
    cursorPos =  findNode(selObj.anchorNode.parentNode.childNodes,
                        selObj.anchorNode) + selObj.anchorOffset;
/* FIXME the following works wrong in Opera when the document is longer than 32767 chars */
    }
    else if (document.selection)
    {
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        var bookmark = range.getBookmark();
/* FIXME the following works wrong when the document is longer than 65535 chars */
        cursorPos = bookmark.charCodeAt(2) - 11; /* Undocumented function [3] */

    }

return cursorPos;
}

function findNode(list, node)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    {
        if (list[i] == node) 
        {
            return i;
    }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Is there any other method to do this?
The new element may be in the middle of the HTML ie, it may not be always at the end.

Thank You

Comment: Text is a leaf node in the DOM. So the best way is to scrape the text out, get the parent element. Delete the child (text) add the new elements, split the text (now a string), and appendChild after creating new Text nodes.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't get you. (" So the best way is to scrape the text out, get the parent element"). Are you suggesting to get the text node, using the cursor position, split the text into 2, append text1,newhtml,text2 (in that order) ? But what if there are other html elements as childern before the text?

Comment: I'm sorry about the previous comment but this did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's part of the method I used. It works but I dont know if there are better ways.

```
function getCursorNode()
{
if (window.getSelection)
{
    var selObj = window.getSelection();
    return selObj.anchorNode;
}
}

function splitTextNode(pos) 
{

selNode=getCursorNode();
if(selNode.nodeName=="#text")
{
    var value=selNode.nodeValue;
    if(value.length == pos)
    {
        return ({"node":selNode,"txt":value }); 
    }
    else if(pos==0)
    {
        return ({"node":selNode,"txt":""}); 
    }
    else
    {                           
        var splittxt1=value.slice(0,pos)
        var tempsplit1=document.createTextNode(splittxt1);

        var splittxt2=value.slice(pos)
        var tempsplit2=document.createTextNode(splittxt2);

        myInsertAfterMany([tempsplit1,tempsplit2],selNode);
        child.parentNode.removeChild(selNode);

        return ({"node":tempsplit1,"first":false,"txt":splittxt1});
    }

}
```

}

But, it(getCursorNode) does not work in IE.
Now, I append the required node after "node" after checking for "first"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var text = $("#container").html();//the target element has the id of container
```

Process `text` now, that is break up `text` the way you want or whatever you want to do with it and add html elements at the relevant position in this `text` using string addition.

Then do this ...

```
$("#container").html(text);
```

You can also take Keith's approach. It's important to realize what he said. Another way to look into it would be inserting a dom element (e.g., html tags) inside text may not be possible with `insertAfter` or `insertBefore`.

Comment: As I understand, that will give me the JavaScript equivalent of innerHTML. Then ,how would I locate the position  of the cursor with that HTML string?

Comment: @Diff.Thinkr: Are you trying to find the coordinates of the top left corner of the selected text? Your computation would probably be correct for monospaced -- fixed width fonts. However, this will be incorrect in most situations for fonts with varying widths. I think you can still use this rough approximation for your purposes. If this is not the issue here, could you elaborate a bit more what you are trying to achieve?